# When I turn the bathroom light off it doesn't always go off

Tags: switch, light

The light always comes on but I often have to switch it 2 or 3 times to get it to go off.

Comment: Is there a reason you think it isn't the switch being broken?

Comment: I am rather new to DIY and am a bit leery about electrical - how do you know if it is just a switch that needs replaced or something serious that requires an electrician?

Comment: Do you mean "switching it on and off two or three times to switch it off?" Is it a plain switch, or something fancy, like a dimmer or lighted switch?

Comment: It is a plain switch. You have to turn it on to off several times before it turns the light out. This happens about 50% of the time. Sometimes it goes right off.

Comment: If you're new to DIY,  I strongly recommend against doing any work yourself.  Get an electrician or a friend who's an engineer or home-DIY type and let them replace the switch.  Watch what they do & you've started learning!

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the switch, it sounds very much like the one you have isn't working correctly.